# How do i make and attache action to button

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Hello I have created a button on my Odoo 10 form "SET geprint" now i want to attach an action to the button. If i press the button the value of the boolean geprint must change to 1. How can I make this possible?

If possible i would also like to create that button in the list view to update multiple records. 
Thx for your help

[image]

I tried your code but i am getting the following error now
(name field to update is x_geprint)
button code :

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a server action (settings - > technical - > Server actions)
[image: Save the action if you want you can add the action to the action menu]

After that search for the action number in your link please see image (my number is 638)
[image]

Then go to the form where you want to add the button. In my example its stock.move

Go into edit formview and add the following code

```
<button name="638" string=" Set geprint" type="action" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via **following methods**.

1. Create **object type of button** in form view. you can give button **type="object"**, after that when you click on button then system will call **python method** In which you can write your code.

ex:

```
<button name="validate" string="Validate" type="object" states="draft" class="oe_highlight"/> 

@api.multi
def validate(self):
    self.write({})
    return True
```

2. For the **list view you need to create new wizard**, In which  you can **select number of records from list view** and in list view **Action** select **your wizard name item**.

Ex:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, _

class test(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'test.test'


<act_window name="Name String" res_model="wizard.model"
    src_model="source.model" view_mode="form" view_type="form"
    target="new" multi="False" 
    id="your_id"
    view_id="view_id"           
    context="{}"/>
```

In **source model Action menu** you can select **wizard link** and In the wizard **you will get active_ids in context**.

**active_ids means all list-view selected records**, based on that you can do it any operations with selective records.

This may help you.