# How to show and change the state in tree view

Tags: odoo-10

I want to show the state change field in tree view. Usually we did this in form view. For example in form view state can be changed from draft to done. I need like this type of state change in tree view also. can you give  a solution to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via **Wizard process**, In **More/Action option** you can **create** new wizard for update state.

Ex :

```
class test(models.TransientModel):
    _name="update.state"    

    state=fields.Selection([('draft','draft'),('done','done')])
    @api.multi 
    def **update_state_ept**(self)
       active_ids=self._context.get(active_ids)
       records=self.env[model].search(active_ids).write({'state':self.state})
```

You can select records from tree view and open wizard from More/Action Menu,select state & update it.

Above example is just an update state, you can put **different conditions** based on your requirement.

Ex: If record is draft then we can confirm it.

You can create following answer for create new wizard in **more/action** menu item.

[How do i make and attache action to button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556087/how-do-i-make-and-attache-action-to-button/43556253#43556253)

This may help you.